# Convergence of series: $\log\left(1 + \frac1{n\sqrt{n}}\right )$

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms

I need to find if this series converges or diverges:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \log\left(1+{1\over(n\sqrt{n})}\right)$$

I'm taking calculus III, so I'm allowed to use these test: nth root test, ratio test, nth term test, limit comparison test, direct comparison test, alternating series test.

Comment: the series diverges

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner No, the series converges.

Comment: yes you have right it is the comparison test

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner If the p series had a p<1 then it would diverge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so I use this $0<ln(1+{1\over(n\sqrt{n}})< 1/(n\sqrt n)$
and then I compare using Direct Comparison Test. Which gives us that the series converges since the $\sum_{n=1}^\infty1/(n\sqrt n)$ is a geometric p-series with p>1.

Comment: Yes, you have it!  Well done!

Answer (score 6):

**HINT:**

$$0<\log(1+x)\le x$$

for $x>0$.  Now use the comparison test.

Answer (score 0):

Such series is obviously less than
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}=\zeta\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) $$
and obviously greater than
$$ \log(2)+\log\prod_{p\in\mathcal{P}}\left(1+\frac{1}{p^{3/2}}\right)=\log\left(\frac{2\,\zeta(3/2)}{\zeta(3)}\right). $$